# Proving a limit of a sequence equals a fixed point

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, numerical-methods

> The iteration  $x_{k + 1} = \frac{1}{2}(x_{k}^{2} + c)$
>   where $0 < c < 1$ has two fixed points $\zeta_{1}$, $\zeta_{2}$, where
>   $0 < \zeta_{1} < 1 < \zeta_{2}$. Show that
>
> $$x_{k + 1} - \zeta_{1} = \frac{1}{2}(x_{k} + \zeta_{1})(x_{k} -
>  \zeta_{1}) $$
>
> and show $\lim_{k\to\infty} x_{k} = \zeta_1$ whenever $0 \leq x_{0} <
>  \zeta_{2}$

I've done the first part, but I can't prove the limit. I have no idea how to show the limit. To do the first part, I just subtracted the iteration equation with the fixed point equation and used difference of squares.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There seems to be a typo in the last line of the problem because $\zeta$ isn't defined anywhere that I can see.

Comment: $\zeta_{1}$ i mean

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=(x^2+c)/2$. Then $x<f(x)<\zeta_1$ if $x\in[0,\zeta_1)$ and $\zeta_1<f(x)<x$ if $x\in(\zeta_1,\zeta_2)$.

If $x_0=\zeta_1$, the $x_n=\zeta_1$ for all $n$.

Take now $x_0\in[0,\zeta_1)$. Then, using the first of the above inequalities, it is easy to see that the sequence of iterates $\{x_n\}$ is increasing and bounded by $\zeta_1$. Therefore it converges, and the limit is precisely \zeta_1$.

Similarly, if $x\in(\zeta_1,\zeta_2)$, then $\{x_n\}$ is decreasing, bounded below by $\zeta_1$ and converges to $\zeta_1$.